# Missing box of duplicates for a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

Just ran across [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650919/using-implicitly-typed-local-variables?rq=1) when I noticed it was closed as a duplicate, but the box showing what it was a duplicate of was gone.

> [image]

<sub>My best free-hand just for meta</sub>

The post is 5 years old, so it could be something with it's age. I remember at some point long ago that the duplicate box was inserted *directly into* the post body, but it seems that even the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/650919/revisions) does not include it.

I made a simple edit to see if the post would re-render itself, but no dice.

So, what's up? What happened?

Comment: Sure, no problem. The age of the question was the problem (more accurately, when it was closed). The duplicate link didn't used to be automatically inserted in the body of the post. Luckily Marc had posted a comment, so it was easy to find the right question to close as a duplicate of.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Looking at the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/650919/revisions), it was a duplicate of 3 posts.

Comment: One is closed and another is deleted, so I just picked the third. There are probably a lot more related questions to these that can be closed as well.

Comment: Here's another with a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828150/extract-floating-number-from-a-string-in-python