# Why was the closing of this question so unusual?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, revision-history

I recently came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421902/any-free-open-source-refactoring-tools) ([web archive for <10k users](http://web.archive.org/web/20140729225156/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421902/any-free-open-source-refactoring-tools)) in a different meta post.

The post is now deleted, but before that, it was closed as a duplicate back in 2009 (I believe it was January, but I can't see the question to confirm).  However, it was a very odd duplicate/closed question:

- It was closed by a [single user (gbjbaanb)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13744/gbjbaanb) who is not a moderator currently.  And the name is not familiar to me as moderator or employee from the recent past (since moderators lose their diamond on their actions once they are no longer a mod there would be no outward sign of a mod closure).  And this was well before gold tag badge users has the power to unilaterally close questions as duplicates.
- The duplicate message was missing.  In that time, the duplicate message was edited into the question, rather than added as a banner, so it was possible to edit the message out.  However, there was no revision history on that post, so an edit to remove that header never happened (or was not recorded).  And the closure happened well after the 5 minute grace period expired, so it wasn't even a quick closure and edit to remove the header.
- When manually going to the [revisions URL (`posts/421902/revisions`)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/421902/revisions), you can see the post was actually closed as a duplicate of 2 different questions (and also you can see there was no 2nd revision created to add the duplicate notice, or 3rd revision to remove it).

So I guess I have 2 questions:

1. What happened to the duplicate message?  How did it get removed when there was no revision to add it or remove it?  Or did it never exist?
2. What special powers did  the close voter have that allow him/her to close the question as a duplicate of 2 different posts on his/her own?  Was he a mod at the time (although that wouldn't address the 2nd duplicate link)?  Or were there other close voters who have been scrubbed from the revision history?

I have no specific interest in the question.  It is off-topic now and was rightfully closed, but I am only curious about why this specific question appears to be unique in the circumstances around its closure.

Comment: @gbjbaanb your presence is requested. *Who was the mysterious closer* you say that like he's gone. He's been gone for an hour at most, and asking him about it would probably be insightful. Maybe things worked differently back in 2009.

Comment: I never said he was gone (although he hasn't ventured on to meta in almost 4 months).

Comment: It never hurts to ask. I'm sure he's a nice, well-meaning, SO user. Maybe there's a time paradox.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET correct.... I didn't explicitly mention that but tried to hint at that point.  I should beeen more explicit.

Comment: FWIW former moderators (and present ones as well) typically carry [Sheriff badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3109/sheriff)

Comment: Your missing banner could be related to this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272103/missing-box-of-duplicates-for-a-question

Comment: @gunr2171 that is probably source the missing duplicate message.  IIRC, the closure of the post in question pre-dated that one.

Comment: Perhaps http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254589/when-did-i-get-close-vote-superpowers ?

Comment: @fadden nope - I addressed that in my question.  The closure happened long before gold tag badge holders got the power to close questions on their own.

Comment: For <10K users, here's a snapshot from the Internet Archive that captures all the unusual components: https://web.archive.org/web/20140729225156/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421902/any-free-open-source-refactoring-tools

Comment: @psubsee2003 off topic but I just noticed: how do you have 24k rep on MSE but only 4k on SO?

Comment: @StevenPenny I have learned a lot about Stack Exchange to be able to answers questions about it - but I am a self-taught novice programmer.  I know enough to not need to ask questions on SO, but not enough to answer too many questions

Comment: I do know that when closing was first introduced, duplicates did not add anything to the post. Editing a box into the post with the Community user was introduced at a later time. Probably because of all the confusion a "this is a duplicate" notice with no links caused. I have no idea about the single-user closures though. Apparently closing as a duplicate only required one vote for some time?

Comment: @animuson looking at some of the posts that senshin linked, it was not limited to duplicates

Comment: I have no idea what has happened! I don't go around marking posts as duplicate for no reason, and dupes usually have to be pretty obvious for me to mark them. I've never been a mod, but the post says it was deleted by 3 other users, not me, when I looked at it just now (on my phone) - deduplicator, Louis, ben75 7 hours ago.  It's a 'rec a tool' question so i think it would still be closed even today.

Comment: @gbjbaanb I wasn't actually calling you out.... it was just unusual and made me wonder.  It was definitely deleted by 3 people (deletion was done today as I "witnessed" it happen).  But the closing was interesting since you were the only person listed.  Since you were around at that time, do you remember anything specific about the close process that would explain it?

Comment: Nope, nothing unusual except that I was the only one to flag it, dupes usually get slapped immediately! It's OK, no offense taken here, and tbh I'm quite intrigued by it too now :-)

Comment: Only surviving user account, probably.  If none were left then Community gets it.  Perhaps a dbase upgrade that purged the dead accounts as well.

Comment: @HansPassant does deletion completely remove someone from the close banner?  I thought it just removed the link to someone's profile, but kept your name at the time of deletion.

Comment: I've never seen a close banner with a delete user account name.  Doesn't prove much but fits the bill.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't know of an example post off the top of my head, but I am pretty sure that the current design just removes the link but leaves the name.  Doesn't mean that removal of the name didn't happen in past.  At the moment that speculation is as good as any of the other possibilities.

Comment: @HansPassant At least as of July 2009, the names of deleted users are not removed from the closure infobox. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1067672/.

Comment: Related to your first bullet item (lack of any indication of former mod action) is the feature request [Binding closevotes should be recorded for moderators as they are for gold badge owners](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240169/).

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In spite of all the downvotes on his answer, [nicael is absolutely correct](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281615/why-was-the-closing-of-this-question-so-unusual/281647#281647) - the notion that privileged users would have to *vote* to close was [a somewhat late addition to the Stack Overflow system](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/i-move-to-close-this-question/):

> As an active Stack Overflow user, one of the abilities you’ll gain at 3,000 reputation is **the ability to close and reopen questions.** Closed questions don’t allow any new answers to be added, but can still be edited and commented on. All it takes is one user (with the appropriate reputation level, natch) to decide a question is closed.

That's the introduction to the blog post that announced the close *voting* system on **December 31, 2008**. From that date onward, questions could only be closed when *multiple* people who had earned the close privilege voted.

So that's the history, but it doesn't explain why the question you saw - which was closed a week *after* this change went into effect - still only lists one closer...

Well, the vote-to-close system we all know and, uh, love now didn't exactly spring into existence *fully-formed* on that day. Some differences are obvious from that blog post - it only took 3 votes to close initially, not five - but others you'll have to dig through [the comments](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/i-move-to-close-this-question/#comment-11624) or old bug reports to identify... Or have a good memory and a long history here. The three relevant differences here:

- **Only the name of the last closer was recorded.** Three voted, but only one name was given under the question or in the revision history. The earliest date I can find for multiple recorded close voters is January **16,** 2009, more than  week after the question you found was closed.
- **Votes were not necessarily preserved after closure.** Nowdays, every single close vote you cast is forever recorded in the system - even if you later retract it or delete your account. But for several *years*, this wasn't necessarily the case - some votes got hard-deleted. Over numerous database migrations and changes to the underlying logic, the system we have today eventually emerged and data that could be recovered or synthesized was, but some votes - and voters - are forever lost to time.
- **Duplicate links weren't recorded at all.** Indeed, the system didn't even prompt for duplicate links until [**May 20, 2009**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/) - and even then, all it did was record the link in an automatic edit in a manner modeled after [the ad-hoc method already being used by some close voters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610728/how-to-handle-duplicate-questions/610795#610795). During the revamp of the duplicate-handling system in early 2013, Jarrod used black magic to identify probable links to duplicate questions for those closed prior to this date, and recorded them in the post history and links tables... But, sometimes, sacrificing a regex at midnight on the night of a full moon just summons Cthulhu.

So what probably happened here was, multiple people voted to close but only the name of the last voter was recorded. The names of the other voters are now lost to time.

And now you know... the rest of the story.

Comment: And, uh, love pattern http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20625/how-can-a-question-be-closed-by-a-single-non-moderator-user

Comment: I may not have been as enthusiastic about suddenly having to vote as some...

Comment: _"In spite of all the downvotes on his answer..."_ Downvotes? What downvotes? Should we delete that part since it is no longer relevant?

Comment: @theknightD2 there's still a bunch of downvotes on it, but there are a lot more upvotes

Answer (score 37):

In the dark old times, there was no *close voting*... but *closing*. Any user with required privileges could close a question and probably choose multiple dupe targets (sure there was such a *possibility*, which could be even achieved with a hack, but anyway: you'll find many such questions there or on MSE...)

Earlier, when a question was closed as dupe, the dupe message was edited in the q body by Community, and removed when the question was reopened, but this could be done only when this notice ended with commented out "end of automatically inserted message" - or something similar - so if a careless edit occurred, this message remained there after reopening and someone would have to edit it out by (him/her)self.

As this message could be easily edited out or changed, now it is not included in the q body.

Comment: When closing was first introduced in August 2008, [three votes were required](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261757/839601): "Allowing a single person with 3,000 rep to close a question isn’t really in the spirit of having a consensus that SO was founded on..."

Comment: In addition to the source @gnat referenced that disputes your first point, your 2nd & 3rd paragraphs are already addressed in the question.  There were no other revisions, just the initial revision, so it would be impossible for the dup message to be edited out unless someone scrubbed the revision from the database.

Comment: I'm afraid that's simply untrue, @gnat. This answer is mostly accurate, although the dup-handling logic it describes wasn't added until well after the question discussed here was closed. [See my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281615/why-was-the-closing-of-this-question-so-unusual/281664#281664) for details.

Comment: @Shog9 I missed the date on the blog completely.  Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 10):

EDIT: Okay, all that stuff down there is actually overkill. It looks like [**absolutely every post closed on or before mid-day 16 Jan 2009**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/262355/closures-early-in-sos-history) in fact lists only one user as responsible for closing.

---

This is more an extended comment than an answer, but: if you take a look at [**this query**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/262318/mysterious-closures-by-a-single-non-moderator), you'll see a number of other anomalous cases where a single user closed a question. In particular, scroll down to the ones where the user is Community - there's around 200 of these that appear to have been closed by a single non-moderator. For example:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/146644/1535629
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/30374/1535629
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/208976/1535629
- [c++ integer->std::string conversion. Simple function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273908/1535629)
- [Split a Pascal-case string into logical set of words](https://stackoverflow.com/q/291804/1535629)
- [Problem with relative path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/319037/1535629)

(It's possible there are some false positives - I don't know that I managed to filter out *all* moderators, past and present. There are almost certainly false negatives, but that shouldn't matter.)

The last of these single-non-moderator closures via Community appears to happen [on 16 January 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/449273/revisions). I don't know what changed then, but I figure something must have. A brief scan of MSO and MSE posts around that timeframe doesn't suggest anything obvious. It looks like [UserVoice hadn't been fully displaced even by June 2009](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/966/224428) - [the site is wiped now](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507034201/https://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/forums/1722-general), but if anybody has an archive of that, it may be worth trawling through.

Comment: Oy.... that answer to the first question in your list is terrible.

Comment: @psubsee2003 flag the heck out of it.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski already done

Comment: @psubsee2003 not that it matters - deletion is preeeety likely.

Comment: What happened on January 16 is simply that the system started recording multiple close-voters in post history. The story behind this is somewhat more interesting though - until a few weeks prior, [there would only ever *be* one closer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281615/why-was-the-closing-of-this-question-so-unusual/281664#281664).

Comment: What? Half of the links are broken, 2 have been flagged and only one is good! What kind of answer is this?!?

Comment: @theknightD2 the links are not broken, you simply don't have the privilege to see them, you need 10k to see deleted posts.