# What were the original rules for posting on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, flags, scope, close-reasons, stack-overflow-history

When people ask why there is so much old, upvoted content that would not be tolerated if posted today, it is often commented that the rules were "different" back then. For example, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136387/should-we-salvage-old-highly-upvoted-questions-instead-of-deleting-them) on Meta.SE. The existence of the Historical Lock itself testifies to some level of scope change.

What were the *original* rules for posting on Stack Overflow? I'm talking about the elder days, when dinosaurs walked the earth and Jon Skeet was still under 3k, yea, even 2008 of memory.

From old posts that I have encountered, it seems that I can guess as to the following:

- Primarily opinion-based and resource request questions were allowed.
- Link-only answers were discouraged, but were tolerated and sometimes even upvoted.
- Spam and hate speech were still banned.

Has a copy of the original requirements for questions and answers been preserved, or can someone give a summary of what content was and was not allowed at the time the site launched?

For example (these are not additional questions, but springboards to help with the original question):

- To the extent that certain now-banned content was allowed back then, was it simply allowed *without restriction* or was there some level of regulation, even if less strict than today? For example, perhaps resource request questions were allowed, but only for books and tools, and asking for *tutorial* recommendations was banned even then.
- On the other hand, was there any content that was *banned* back then but is now *allowed*? For example, maybe programming questions on Visual Basic 6 were originally considered off-topic, with that changing in the VB6 Liberation Wars of Summer 2010.

Comment: There's never -- then or now -- been an explicitly enumerated list of commandments like this. For better or worse, we operate largely under the [Stewart obscenity rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it "I know it when I see it").

Comment: 1. Do not expose a question to bright lights. 2. Do not let a question get wet. 3. Do not feed a question after midnight. At least, that's how I remember it.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I think we failed at point 3 :)

Comment: @ChrisF, yes that was how VB6 questions got here. ;)

Comment: @visibleman which side were *you* on in the VB6 Liberation Wars? My father didn't fight, he was a DBA for some accounting firm.

Comment: There were separate rules for Fridays. And for Iceland.

Comment: @Teemu I was trying more to be poetic than to really limit the question.

Comment: @RobertColumbia My afilliation flags are stored in an array, but the evil side always gets the offset wrong.

Comment: @JoshCaswell If we really operated under that rule, 90% of what's posted as "questions" nowadays would be nuked.

Comment: Big difference back then was in tolerance of list questions, and jokes, and particularly lists of jokes

Answer (score 65, accepted):

In case anyone was not aware, Stack Overflow was co-founded by Joel Spolsky and Jeff Atwood. Their original outlook is essentially what the original "rules" were.

However, there were no *exact* rules, because when it first started, as with many online startups, the largest hurdle was onboarding.

> The hardest thing about making a new Q&A site is not the programming—it’s the community. You need a large audience of great developers so you have the critical mass it takes to get started. -[Joel Spolsky](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/09/15/stack-overflow-launches/)

Luckily the founders were very popular bloggers and already had quite a following, so the onboarding process had a head start. The format quickly attracted many other exceptional problem solvers.

> In the beginning of August, the beta opened to a small group of just a few hundred developers. The site lit up instantly! People were asking questions and, for the most part, getting answers! -[Joel Spolsky](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/09/15/stack-overflow-launches/)

Stack Overflow was seemingly started as a vision quest.

> It is by programmers, for programmers, with the ultimate intent of collectively increasing the sum total of good programming knowledge in the world. -[Jeff Atwood](https://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/)

Jeff goes on to explain that this goal was created because

> There's far too much great programming information trapped in forums, buried in online help, or hidden away in books that nobody buys any more. We'd like to unlock all that. Let's create something that makes it easy to participate, and put it online in a form that is trivially easy to find.

Day 1 of Stack Overflow, there was no closure, nor deletion (aside from staff deleting content), there was no community moderation whatsoever (unless you want to consider personal communications outside of the platform).

Joel's vision for questions was

> Every question in Stack Overflow is like the Wikipedia article for some extremely narrow, specific programming question. How do I enlarge a fizzbar without overwriting the user’s snibbit? This question should only appear once in the site. Duplicates should be cleaned up quickly and redirected to the original question. -[Joel Spolsky](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/09/15/stack-overflow-launches/)

It was a free for all, and as happens in all organized chaos, that came with both advantages and disadvantages. Much of the advice Joel gives during the launch blog post is simply bad advice in today's environment. He realized that over time the rules would change though, even during launch stating

> [This is] how it’s supposed to work. This is a community project, so I’m being careful to avoid saying this is how it will work… that’s up to the community. But this is roughly what I have in mind. -[Joel Spolsky](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/09/15/stack-overflow-launches/)

Over time, the rules evolved. You can read most of the evolution if you go through Joel's http://joelonsoftware.com, Jeff's http://codinghorror.com, MSE http://meta.stackexchange.com, the blog https://stackoverflow.blog/?blb=1, and the podcasts https://stackoverflow.blog/podcasts/page/42/. Make sure to set aside some time if you are intent on getting through all of it, 6-8 weeks should do.

Comment: For posterity, do you have an exact date for "Day 1 of Stack Overflow"? (We might want to base a new calender on it.)

Comment: Public availability [seems to have been on or about Sept 16, 2008](https://blog.codinghorror.com/stack-overflow-none-of-us-is-as-dumb-as-all-of-us/), @usr2564301

Comment: Seems like Joel's vision changed markedly somewhere along the way.

Comment: @JoshCaswell [it was Sept. 16, 2008](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/09/15/stack-overflow-launches/) as Joel Spolsky writes that SO launched today in his blogpost on that date

Comment: @Ian_Kemp, that's a very unfair comment, even for meta. Please, explain what you mean? You've received a "helpful" flag and while I may know what you mean... you should **really** do all of us justice by posting something more. (I'm not baiting you. Probably feel the same way you do too. But seriously? Your comment would normally be flagged as "unfriendly or unkind" if only because you've not defined it.

Comment: @Jelmergu: as the first "real world" (= non-developer) question in the public beta was posted [August 1, 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19/2564301) that means developing the public beta into its current form took exactly 6-8 weeks.

Comment: "*There's far too much great programming information trapped in forums, buried in online help, or hidden away in books that nobody buys any more. We'd like to unlock all that*". What a ridiculously difficult undertaking.

Comment: Small correction: *closing* was there from day one - [it just worked very differently from the way it does today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116523/string-vs-string). Non-admin deletion existed too, but was quickly [limited to folks deleting their own stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38/reliable-timer-in-a-console-application). For folks with 10K, [the first closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19797/best-bluetooth-stereo-headphone) presents a good illustration of stuff that was deemed inappropriate right from the start.

Comment: @Shog9 - Thanks, those are interesting posts. Do you have any material explaining the mechanisms to link to? Or perhaps you could share some of  your knowledge here in an answer :) While this answer is representative of the outlook when the site opened, it does not explicitly outline rules per se.

Comment: I talk a bit about the evolution of the closing system here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281615/why-was-the-closing-of-this-question-so-unusual/281664#281664

Answer (score 68):

A quick look at [The Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20081003061320/http://stackoverflow.com:80/faq) gives the following original rules for Stack Overflow (per 3 October, 2008):

> ### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Programming questions, of course! As long as your question is:
>
> - detailed and specific
> - written clearly and simply
> - of interest to at least one other programmer somewhere
>
> ### What kind of questions should I not ask here?
>
> Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is a place for questions that can be answered!
>
> ### Be nice.
>
> ### Be honest.

Comment: Beautiful. So short and yet says everything that matters.

Comment: Put this back on the help page! Make Stack Overflow great again!

Comment: I agree.  Reading this posts I keep thinking how every "Rule" has made SO just a little worse.  Those old closed posts that wouldn't be allowed under todays "Rules" are typically some of the best, most important content we've created.

Comment: Nice find! That link is a great read, perhaps a discussion on its relevance in today's environment would be productive.

Comment: These rules would disqualify 90% of the crap that is posted as "questions" nowadays, hence why they were nuked.

Comment: Those will always be my rules, no matter what SE management wants.

Answer (score 14):

I don't think that the original requirements were actually written down, so you won't find a list that enumerates what sort of posts were allowed. For example "as a programmer" type questions were allowed in the early days, but that "rule" wasn't written down. In fact the only time that it was written down was when they were deemed to be off topic, with the introduction of the "Not Programming Related" close reason and ultimately the creation of the site that became "Programmers".

What you might find, if you search the blog, podcasts, here, [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) and (if it still exists) User Voice, are the posts where rule changes were discussed and agreed, or posts where employees announced new policies. These changes would usually come about after people noticed certain behaviours and questioned whether they were useful or not.

Comment: Don't forget the early podcasts and blogs. Those predate MSE.

Comment: @rene oh yeah. And User Voice too.

Comment: Yeah, but the UserVoice content is considered lost.

Comment: So originally the site didn't have any close reasons at all?

Comment: If you showed up on the first day, could you actually ask about the rain in Spain or 21st century best practices in underwater basket weaving (that is, without getting your question closed or otherwise subjected to similar adverse action) or was there still a "must somehow relate to programming, even in a vague way" rule?

Comment: @BSMP I'm fairly sure it did, and that you only needed one vote, but I can't remember what they were. I mentioned the "as a programmer" rule as an example of something that was originally allowed but then disallowed.

Comment: @RobertColumbia, I wasn't around on day one (it's my 10 year anniversary next month) but I'm fairly sure the site operated on "good faith" and assumed that you weren't going to ask non-programming questions.

Comment: Some history about the most famous "...as a programmer" question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about @RobertColumbia