# How do new rules come into Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions

I was reading this [interesting thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378331/what-were-the-original-rules-for-posting-on-stack-overflow) about the rules of Stack Overflow in the early days.

I was just wondering who sets the rules and regulations of Stack Overflow?

Is it a top-down approach or a bottom-up approach? In either case, how does the management decide to introduce the new rules and regulation? Is there any kind of rule enhancement proposal like Python has (Python Enhancement Proposal)?

Comment: Both. The ratio started with a high ratio of “bottom up” (community, as discussed , debated, and ultimately determined on meta) to “top down” (company, by corporate fiat). Over time that’s been reversed (particularly in recent quarters); now it’s more “top down” than “bottom up”. This has caused some friction on meta.

Comment: @DanBron then my question would be who is in top management who make those decisions? Is there any cabinet kind of thing? Who elects them?

Comment: It's a business and not all it's internal processes are transparent. As a business it does not have to share these things. The conflict it is a community driven site being run by a corporation.

Comment: I find that recently the idea that it's "bottom-up" is laughable. The Stack Exchange corporation has most definitely been making "the rules" recently and even if they are very poorly received by the community, moderators, contributors, they are here to stay, with little to no alterations.

Comment: *"Is it a top-down approach [...]?"* It is now.

Comment: The software basically decides what can be done with it and the software is completely under control of the company. Then there is the code of conduct, which the company updates regularly. With the community it's a bit more unclear. It's a bunch of individuals with some common goals and they may or may not do what the company wants. For example they may use the software in a differently than preferred by the company. Somehow both parts rely on each other and need each other and therefore the rules are determined also by the community. It's an asymmetric power struggle, a bit like politics.