# This question already has answers where?

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions

I was looking at this question:
[What is meant with "const" at end of function declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141087/what-is-meant-with-const-at-end-of-function-declaration)... and there is a blue box indicating where there are already answers but after the colon it is just a timestamp followed by some people.

Then a yellow box shows a "possible" duplicate. Something's off about all this. I think it's a bug, result of an update, I'm not sure what to make of it exactly so I thought I would share my experience here.

[image]

Comment: [So irony](https://i.imgur.com/ba2vhYh.png)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That is an old question, closed as a duplicate back before the current system was in place. Back then, all that happened is that [the Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/) (a bot with moderator privileges) edited in the "possible duplicate" banner to the question's actual text. It wasn't tracked as an actual duplicate, and it was vulnerable to being inadvertently (or intentionally) removed by subsequent editors.

This left an even more noticeable gap when the new notification system rolled out, which changed the color and positioning of the banners. There was no field in the database referencing the purported duplicate, so there's nothing for the notification banner to link to.

This [has been noted before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337282), but there's no good way of automatically correcting these—mass editing of a bunch of questions always makes me nervous, and, as I mentioned above, that "possible duplicate of" banner may not have survived intact over the years. Instead, we just correct them manually by re-opening and closing as a duplicate of the same post. Any gold badge holder can do this with a single vote and a minimum of fuss, as can a diamond moderator.

I've addressed the problem in this case; you should now be seeing the correct notification banner. If you come across additional anomalous questions, please raise a moderator flag or ping a gold badge holder in chat (if you're a regular anywhere where they hang out).

Comment: Should one flag such a post for moderator attention?

Comment: @leonheess I firmly believe so, yes. However, Martijn's instincts apparently told him something different. That's bound to happen when you have humans as moderators; we're not all created equal. We are discussing it internally, and will let you know what the conclusion is. Sorry for the confusion that this created.

Comment: @CodyGray: So what was the result of the discussion? Should normal users flag such questions for moderator or not?

Comment: The internal discussion didn't exactly reach a conclusion, @Amit. Some other things interrupted. I still say "yes".

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to write a script that goes through the Community user's edit history, finds edits with the edit summary "insert duplicate link", check the page that the link inserted in that edit points to and insert that link into the database?

Comment: @DonaldDuck Perhaps. You volunteer to write the script, I'll volunteer to help fix them.

Comment: @CodyGray I tried starting to write a query in the data explorer to find those posts, and I noticed that there *is* actually a field in the database referencing the duplicate despite what you say in your answer. For example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18584/4284627) has the problem mentioned in this question, yet if you run [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/1255829/1545876/) you will see that both that question's ID and the original's ID are present.

Comment: By the way (this has nothing to do with the topic discussed here) I think it's weird that the asker of the question I mentioned in my previous comment has a user ID greater than the post ID of the question (1130097 > 18584). Wouldn't that mean that at the time that question was posted the site had more users than posts?

Comment: @DonaldDuck For the unrelated question, user 1548 was merged into user 1130097 *many* years ago, so presumably they asked the question under account 1548. On the other topic, I'm not sure the details of how this is stored in the database. I'm not a Stack Exchange developer, so those details are only based on what I've heard. If the information is there but not being used, then that's a Stack Exchange bug, and the developers should be able to re-sync their database fields. It wouldn't solve the manually added "possible duplicate" banner, though; those would need to be manually edited out.

Comment: @CodyGray Should I post that as a bug report in a new question then?

Comment: @DonaldDuck I suppose so. This [has been brought up before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337282), [twice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337326) that I know of. Maybe more times on MSE. And on MSO, see [history here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281664), which is consistent with what you've found, but shows that we can't solve the problem automatically for posts older than May 20, 2009. I would swear that what you're saying has been brought up specifically as a bug, but I can't remember if it was on MSE or MSO, and I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: @CodyGray OK, I posted a new bug report [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349996/349538).

Comment: "but shows that we can't solve the problem automatically for posts older than May 20, 2009." I see about 40,000 live questions [of this sort](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=3&tab=Relevance&q=duplicate%3ayes%20%22Possible%20Duplicate%3a%22%20is%3aq) and [only about 300](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate%3Ayes+%22Possible+Duplicate%3A%22+is%3Aq+created%3A..2009-05-20) seem to be too old to fix automatically. Even then, some really old ones got "merged" ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558/python-and-the-singleton-pattern)).