# Duplicate banner empty flag declined

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

For additional information on the problem encountered: [This question already has answers where?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391505/this-question-already-has-answers-where)

Quote from the accepted answer:

> Any gold badge holder can do this with a single vote and a minimum of fuss, as can a diamond moderator.

Accordingly, I flag those for moderator attention and have been doing so for a while (they are quite rare) and they have been marked as helpful in the past. Both here and on other Stack Exchange sites. However, when I reported the problem on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135126/onclick-vs-addeventlistener), suddenly the flag was declined without any reasoning:

[image]

Did I do something wrong here? Please help me understand.

Comment: Drop by the JS room in SO chat and ping one of the many gold badge holders to sort it out.

Comment: *"Did I do something wrong here?"* In my opinion yes, but I don't think that's your fault. The advice given by Cody is incorrect there. This situation isn't a real problem, thus moderators don't need to be made aware of this.

Comment: it's fixed now .. the banner should be correct

Comment: @TemaniAfif Can you also fix https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783573/preventing-browser-text-input-suggestions ?

Comment: fixed, you can drop them in the chat room if you want: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign . We are two gold badge active there so we can handle them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I declined this flag because gold badge holders can do this, *and it's not really a problem that requires our intervention*. The post isn't broken or hugely confusing, and if it doesn't get fixed today that's not going to cause a huge amount of confusion. Just leave a comment on the post if it bothers you that the banner is empty at the moment and can't find a gold badge holder (in a chat room or similar).

Please keep moderator flags for things that only moderators can do, or if there is a Gordian knot of community disagreement to resolve.

(I wasn't aware of that Meta post and will have a discussion with the other moderators about what advice we give on these things).

Comment: Has there been any conclusion on this matter?