# Duplicate title not updated / missing links

Tags: bug

I'm wondering what's going on here:

[Using domDocument, and parsing info, I would like to get the 'href' contents of an 'a' tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278418/using-domdocument-and-parsing-info-i-would-like-to-get-the-href-contents-of)

First of all, it says:

> This question already has answers here:

Which is then followed by.. *nothing?*  What is it a dupe of? Typically I'd expect to see a link or two in that spot.

Then below it has a section that says:

> Possible Duplicate: [Regular expression for grabbing the href attribute of an A element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element)

Which has an outdated title — the title was edited 9 years ago to read:

> Grabbing the href attribute of an A element

I almost blew off the suggested dupe because it mentions regex in relation to parsing HTML (which is an aberration). Thankfully, someone updated that title, but you wouldn't know it from the dupe page since it wasn't updated there. To me this is problematic since improvements to the title of the question we'd like users to see are not being reflected on the dupe page.

Both of these things seem like bugs to me, and I suspect they are related.  Shouldn't the title of a dupe be something dynamic that changes if the post it refers to is updated?

Comment: Could be that the old post notices pulled the text from the target question at the moment of closure

Comment: that's what I'd guess as well, but I can't imagine why it would be static by design since nothing else on the page is

Comment: @billynoah The duplicate closure system wasn't quite as well-designed back then. If you look at the question's revision history you can see where the Community user "manually" added that text.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery - thanks! I understand.  The answer on that [dupe question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391505/this-question-already-has-answers-where) was quite helpful as well.