# Why was my flag for fixing a duplicate banner declined, even though it followed moderator advice?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I found [PHP Warning Permission denied (13) on session_start()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821532/php-warning-permission-denied-13-on-session-start) which has a broken duplicate banner. I mod-flagged it based on [This question already has answers where?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391505/this-question-already-has-answers-where/391506#391506) which has an accepted answer with an active moderator explicitly stating that for this exact scenario a mod flag is appropriate and should be used. To make sure there is no confusion I referenced the Meta-question in the flag explanation by saying:

> Reporting for incorrect duplicate banner based on meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391506/7910454

I really tried to do everything right but nevertheless, the flag was declined. I am going to be honest: things like this really dampen my motivation to participate in this community.

Is there anything I could have done differently in this case?

Comment: Almost certainly done in error, or due to conflicting guidance, IIRC there's a post somewhere which says not worrying about it, although having trouble finding it. I wouldn't worry about the declined flag though. Also it's useful to specify exactly what you want the mod to do, rather than just describing the issue and expecting them to go read a meta post, their time is limited after all.

Comment: It might be that the mod who handled it wasn't sure what you were asking and didn't visit the link - did you include anything else in the flag text? Perhaps you needed "Per [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391506), the dupe banner is broken, please re-open and then close again"

Comment: In fact, that conflicting guidance I was looking for, is in the comments of that meta post: *"I firmly believe so, yes. However, Martijn's instincts apparently told him something different. That's bound to happen when you have humans as moderators; we're not all created equal."* - Apparently there was a discussion about it that never ended up with a consensus in the mods. Different people think it should be handled differently. /shrug

Comment: @Nick I read that too but punishing users for that uncertainty is certainly the wrong approach IMO. I mean he could have just ignored the flag but instead purposefully declined it.

Comment: A declined flag isn't a punishment

Comment: @Nick Hard to believe when they even serve you warning banners telling you that your last flag was declined and warning you to be more careful or be banned from flagging..

Comment: @leonheess That still doesn't mean a declined flag is "punishment"– it's just the state describing the flag's status. _Punishment_ comes when someone routinely misuses flags and has them continuously declined (i.e. suspension is a punishment). I also don't think "just ignored the flag" is really an option in this case, it's gotta get handled to leave the flag queue. Sometimes a flag can be marked "disputed", but I'm not sure whether or not that's possible in this particular case.

Comment: It sounds like you are saying the duplicate target should be changed. It's probably why it was declined

Comment: Well, the one thing they certainly did achieve is that the next time I see a problem on SO I will take good care not to bring it to someone's attention *shrug*

Comment: I fixed it for you now. No need to involve a moderator. There's little value in doing that though

Comment: @zcoop98 AFAIK, only spam and R/A flags can be disputed. Can't dispute mod flags

Comment: Well, if *this* is the worst thing that's happened with me taking a break from handling flags, I think we're doing OK. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why your flag might have been declined.

- The phrasing of your flag doesn't make it clear what you want to happen. Yes, following the link would make it clear, but you shouldn't use links to convey that. Links should be used only as supporting evidence. As written, your flag could also be interpreted as asking for a duplicate target to be *changed*, which is definitely something a mod will decline to do.
- The mod who handled your flag might have disagreed with the consensus in the linked meta post. As is clear from the [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391505/this-question-already-has-answers-where/391506#comment768731_391506) on the linked meta answer, the mod team hasn't reached an internal consensus on that

  > The internal discussion didn't exactly reach a conclusion, ... - Cody Gray

Even if you phrase the flag correctly, and the handling mod agrees that fixing such duplicate banners is a reasonable thing to do, the mod might have just made a mistake. These things happen, and you shouldn't let it put you off raising flags in the future. A declined flag is not a big deal at all, despite the admittedly scary warning banner you can be presented with.

If you're *sure* that your flag is valid, you can raise another flag on the post. This is not something you should make a habit of doing, but it's an option. Be sure to mention your previous flag, and of course, be explicit with what you want to happen. Definitely don't do this a third time though.

In this case, fixing a duplicate banner is also something that regular users can do if they have a gold tag-badge, and so you could drop a message in a chat room where such users hang out. This was a PHP question, and there's a reasonably active chat room where PHP users hang out. (You should check the chat room norms before just dropping a link there, as is the case for any chat room). You could also ask in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) since you're not involved in this post, and there are likely users hanging out there who can fix it.

Answer (score -6):

IMHO, using the mod flag is overkill to fix duplicate issues. As mentioned by Cody answer from [This question already has answers where?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391506/3654837):

> Instead, we just correct them manually by re-opening and closing as a
> duplicate of the same post. Any gold badge holder can do this with a
> single vote and a minimum of fuss, as can a diamond moderator.

Emphasis on **as can a diamond moderator.** Which means there is another way to fix the broken duplicate flag.

In an ideal world, if editing an old broken duplicate link doesn't bump the question every broken duplicate would be fixed at this point.

To be fair unless the linked "possible duplicate" banner to the question's actual text is edited out, it doesn't matter if it has a broken duplicate banner.

Comment: This option isn't available to the OP.

Comment: True, because OP opt to directly moderator flag, which is supposed to be last resort.

Comment: There is no flag to bring it to the attention of gold badge holders. What do you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: You don't need to do anything to fix it tbf. Not worth the effort. Nonetheless if you really want to bump the question you can tag the gold badger or go to chat room.