# Misplacement of "possible duplicate"

Tags: discussion, design, duplicate-questions

I was searching for some git stuff and found this question: [Show git diff on file in staging area](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3527856/4438007)

At first, it seemed to me that it was a primary question, but then I've found that it was a duplicate.

See the placement of these informations in the question layout:

[image: misplacement of the "possible duplicate" section]

The light-blue box describes that the question in particular had answers there. Then colon, then "Closed 7 years ago." No obvious link

Shortly after, there was a block-qoute with the sayings "possible duplicate" and the "original" question.

But my common sense says that the colon placement with no more usable data after is a mistake, mainly because the would-be data was placed outside the blue box.

Something like this seems to me to have more sense:

[image: "possible duplicate" section inside the blue box]

Comment: that is an "old style" duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26f8b313-24bc-4278-b134-fe60372beba8/view-source and those older ones never got fixed. Unless someone wants to do a re-open / re-close, but meh. For reference: I did one on MSE earlier today: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39364/add-stack-overflow-user-as-a-favorite see the timeline for what I did: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/39364/timeline

Comment: That is an artifact of how questions used to look when closed.  The possible duplicate link used to be manually edited into the question.  Then it started getting automatically edited.  But people could edit them out unfortunately.  The banner that exists today is relatively new in the site's history

Comment: Some interesting history on the close voting: [Why was the closing of this question so unusual?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281615/why-was-the-closing-of-this-question-so-unusual)